# How to exit infinite for(;TRUE;) in C?

Tags: c, loops, for-loop

I am running a simulation which uses an infinite for loop. TRUE is defined as 1. Inside the loop, each call containing "state" is a function that returns void.

```
/* main sim loop */
for (i = 0, num_insn = 0; TRUE; i++) {
  writeback(state, &num_insn);
  execute(state);
  if (!(state->fetch_lock)) {
    decode(state);
    fetch(state);
  }
}
```

I would like to eventually exit the loop from inside of an "if" statement in the writeback function. How is this done? I tried to use "break" but I get an error when I compile.

EDIT: Inside the writeback function

```
if ((state->fetch_lock == TRUE)&&(fu_int__done == TRUE)&&(fu_fp_add_done ==TRUE)&&(fu_fp_mult_done == TRUE)&&(fu_fp_div_done == TRUE)) {
    break;
}
```

which gives compile error "error: break statement not within loop or switch"

Comment: What is the error message you get?

Comment: Please post the code with break in it

Comment: EDIT above. Sorry.

Comment: `for (i = 0, num_insn = 0; TRUE; i++)` definitely needs a `break` :) But _inside_ the loop. Please post code and the mystery will go away.

Comment: My crystal ball says the `break` is in one of the functions, where there's no loop.

Comment: Post the code with all the necessary ingredients if you want the problem solved :)

Comment: Please edit the question

Comment: Hey, my crystal ball was right! 8vD

Comment: you must call break in main sim loop not inside writeback function

Comment: @FredLarson - Please change your username to mysticmeg.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The `writehack` function can be called from anywhere.

Change it to

```
   bool writeBack(...) {
    ...
    return true; // Break is require if in a loop
    return false; // Otherwise;
```

Then

```
for (i = 0, num_insn = 0; TRUE; i++) {
  if (writeback(state, &num_insn) ) {break; }
  execute(state);
  if (!(state->fetch_lock)) {
    decode(state);
    fetch(state);
  }
}
```

Comment: Sorry the typo was deliberate.

Comment: bool isn't a type in C but I get the gist

Comment: @Kal `bool` (aka `_Bool`) is a type in C.